# Compare two hibernate mapping files

Tags: liquibase

I would like liquibase to compare two hibernate mappings instead of a database as source and a hibernate mapping as reference:

```
liquibase --changeLogFile=c:/tmp/changelog.xml --url=hibernate:classic:c:/tmp/a.xml --referenceUrl=hibernate:classic:c:/tmp/b.xml diffChangeLog
```

That does not seem to work as I am getting an exception:

```
Liquibase diffChangeLog Failed: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /tmp/a.xml not found
```

Is that supposed to work? The idea is to compare two versions (svn revisions) of the same hibernate mapping file and generate a liquibase script.

Comment: It should work. If you run with --logLevel=DEBUG what do you get for a full exception?

Comment: It seems hibernate always uses "the class loader" to load resources, so, file paths will not work, instead use a relative path that is added to the class path.

Comment: @Nathan: I am getting an NPE: liquibase.ext.hibernate.snapshot.TableSnapshotGenerator.snapshotObject(TableSnapshotGenerator.java:82)

Comment: @Nathan: I have just debugged the code of the external hibernate contribution and it seems there is a bug in line 82 of liquibase.ext.hibernate.snapshot.TableSnapshotGenerator... I think it should be 'hibernateTable' instead of 'table' that is queried for the primary key... the question here is if the hibernate contribution/integration of liquibase is mature enough for further evaluation.

Comment: It should be mature enough. That bug is fixed in the master branch and I'm planning on releasing a new version today with the fix in it. Thanks for the debugging.

Comment: @Nathan, I cloned the git repo and the change is in, but there is no new release/build.

Comment: Sorry, taking longer to get out. I'm still working through a few bugs.