# liquibase - Is it possible to compare two packages with jpa annotated classes? and how?

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jpa, liquibase

i'm using the liquibase-hibernate-extension with maven in my spring hibernate application.
And i want to compare an older version from my jpa/hibernate annotated classes to a newer version (For Example im using the same package with no ImprovedNamingStrategy). Like this in my pom.xml:

```
<url>hibernate:spring:com.myc.model?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</url> 
<referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:com.myc.model?hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy&amp;dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</referenceUrl>
```

I'm gettin' this exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.3.2:diff (default) on project model: Error setting up or running Liquibase: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist -> [Help 1]
```

So if im using this for the url in pom.xml everything works perfectly:

```
<url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb</url>
<driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
<username>user</username>
<password>pass</password>
<referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:com.myc.model?hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy&amp;dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</referenceUrl>
```

So is it possible to use hibernate:spring as a prefix for the url and how can i manage it?

I've read this: [Compare two hibernate mapping files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149395/compare-two-hibernate-mapping-files)

I think this should be possible!

Thank you for your answers!

**UPDATE**

The command line tool works perfectly with the settings above. Only the maven plugin runs into the described error.
Full Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.3.2:diff (execution1) on project model: Error setting up or running Liquibase: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error setting up or running Liquibase: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute(AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:373)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.execute(LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more

Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:69)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute(AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:321)
    ... 23 more

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:591)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:443)
    at liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateSpringDatabase.buildConfigurationFromScanning(HibernateSpringDatabase.java:227)
    at liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateSpringDatabase.buildConfiguration(HibernateSpringDatabase.java:55)
    at liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateDatabase.setConnection(HibernateDatabase.java:45)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(DatabaseFactory.java:123)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:143)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:50)
    ... 24 more

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:187)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:588)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: I do not use liquibase-hibernate-extension, so cannot directly answer your question. However, I can provide with a full workflow with example on how to generate automatic DB diffs for annotated classes, and have them applied automatically by a Lilquibase Spring.